# How to convert NSAppleEventDescriptor type 'ldt' to NSDate in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

`NSLog(@"%@",eventDescriptor);` shows `<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'ldt '($90EFCFC700000000$)>`

How do i convert this to NSDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a LongDateTime value, so you'd extract the data as LongDateTime, then maybe pass it through `UCConvertLongDateTimeToCFAbsoluteTime` and then use `+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:]`.